# Get non ASCII character in shell Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, base64

I have a command that return non ASCII encoded base64 result, how to get the result in shell variable.

Any solution to get it?

Example:

```
$ mycommand|base64 -d > f
# verify presence of character with hexdump command
$ hexdump -C f
00000000  06 05 03 01                                       |....|
00000004
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$ a=`mycommand|base64 -d|hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02X"'`
$ echo $a
06050301
```